# PostgreSQL log trigger optimalization

Tags: postgresql, logging, triggers, query-optimization

I spent a lot of time trying to optimize our pgsql log trigger which started to be a problem. I did huge progress (from 18min to 2.5min by inserting 3M rows) but I would like to know if some pgSql masters will be able to do it even better.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_log_trig()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        col TEXT; -- Single column name to save
        newVal TEXT; -- New value for column
        oldVal TEXT; -- Old value for column
        colLimit TEXT[]; -- Columns that should be logged
    BEGIN
        IF TG_ARGV[0] IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- Trigger specifies columns to log
            SELECT array_agg(unnest)
            FROM unnest(string_to_array(TG_ARGV[0], ','))
            INTO colLimit;
        ELSE
        -- Trigger with no params. Log all columns
            SELECT array_agg(json_object_keys)
            FROM json_object_keys(row_to_json(NEW))
            WHERE json_object_keys NOT IN ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at') -- Exceptions
            INTO colLimit;
        END IF;

        -- Loop over columns that should be saved in log
        FOREACH col IN ARRAY colLimit
        LOOP
            -- INSERT & UPDATE
            EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1).' || col || '::text' INTO newVal USING NEW;
            -- UPDATE
            IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
                EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1).' || col || '::text' INTO oldVal USING OLD;
            END iF;
            -- Add only new or changed data
            IF
                newVal != oldVal OR
                (oldVal IS NULL AND newVal IS NOT NULL) OR
                (oldVal IS NOT NULL AND newVal IS NULL)
            THEN
                INSERT INTO tab_logs (record_id, field_name, old_value, new_value, created_at, created_by, action)
                VALUES (NEW.id, col, oldVal, newVal, NOW(), 999, 'O');
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: just a suggestion but your if can be changed from: newVal != oldVal OR
                (oldVal IS NULL AND newVal IS NOT NULL) OR
                (oldVal IS NOT NULL AND newVal IS NULL) to simply isnull(newVal,'') <> oldVal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_to_json()` returns both column names and values; you may as well make use of these values, rather than extracting them later via dynamic SQL.

I haven't thoroughly tested this, let alone benchmarked it, but here's the gist of it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_log_trig() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE
  OldJson JSONB = NULL;
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP <> 'INSERT' THEN
    OldJson := to_jsonb(old);
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO tab_logs (record_id, field_name, old_value, new_value, created_at, created_by, action)
  SELECT new.id, key, OldValues.value, NewValues.value, now(), 999, 'O'
  FROM jsonb_each(to_jsonb(new)) NewValues
  LEFT JOIN jsonb_each(OldJson) OldValues USING (key)
  WHERE
    (
      (TG_ARGV[0] IS NULL AND key NOT IN ('id', 'created_at', 'updated_at')) OR
      (TG_ARGV[0] IS NOT NULL AND key = ANY(string_to_array(TG_ARGV[0], ',')))
    ) AND
    OldValues.value::text IS DISTINCT FROM NewValues.value::text;

  RETURN NULL;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: WOW! 16s -> 8s for 100k rows! So your proposition is 2x faster. Impressive. Thank you!

Comment: Is there options to INSERT INTO log_{TG_TABLE_SCHEMA.TG_TABLE_NAME} without doing EXECUTE on builded string?

Comment: @imclickingmaniac: Not really. In another language (e.g. C) you could keep a cache of prepared `INSERT` statements to avoid re-parsing them, but I'm not sure if it'd be worth the trouble. A simpler solution would be to create a different trigger function for each table.